# android-SurfaceView: "Object is disappearing"

Tags: android, animation, canvas, surfaceview

Aoa. I'm facing a problem with androird surfaceView.. I'm trying to animate a ball by changing its x,y coordinates. But ball is disappearing... Please see the code and identify the issue,
regards.`

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(tile1, axisX, axisY,null);        //LINE ONE objects
    canvas.drawBitmap(tile2, axisX+78, axisY,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(tile3, axisX+156, axisY,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(tile4, axisX+234, axisY,null);


    canvas.drawBitmap(movingStick, (mWidth-movingStick.getWidth())/2, mHeight-200,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBall, balCurrPosX,balCurrPosY  ,null);

}
```

//thread code

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

    private boolean moveUp = true;


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

            while (true) {
            if (balCurrPosY >= mHeight){
                moveUp= false;
            }else if(balCurrPosX<=0){
                moveUp = true;
            }
            if(moveUp)
                balCurrPosY--;
            else
                balCurrPosY++;
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            postInvalidate();
            }


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});`
```

Comment: Are you redrawing the entire screen every time?  Also, if you're going to override `onDraw()`, you should be using a custom View, not a SurfaceView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to start your new Thread at the end of your code :

```
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```